# Fetching NULL datetime value in MySQL using GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to fetch the last visit_details row having out_time as `NULL` using Gorm.
`NIL` is itself a type where VisitDetail OutTime is `mysql.NullTime`.

**Code:-**

```
var visitDetail models.VisitDetail
db.Where("out_time=? ", nil).Last(&visitDetail)

//model VisitDetails
type VisitDetail struct {
    Id              int
    Visitor         Visitor  `gorm:"foreignkey:ClientId;association_foreignkey:Id"`
    VisitorId       int      `gorm:"not null;"`
    Location        Location `gorm:"foreignkey:LocationId;association_foreignkey:Id"`
    LocationId      int      `gorm:"not null;"`
    Purpose         string
    InTime          time.Time `gorm:"not null;"`
    OutTime         mysql.NullTime
    User            User `gorm:"foreignkey:ClientId;association_foreignkey:Id"`
    UserId          int  `gorm:"not null;"`
    Status          int  `gorm:"not null;"`
    ApproveByClient int  `gorm:"not null;"`
}
```

**Query:-**

```
select * from visit_details where out_time is NULL order by id desc limit 1;
+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| id | visitor_id | location_id | purpose | in_time             | out_time | user_id | status | approve_by_client |
+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| 20 |          1 |           8 |         | 2018-02-20 17:13:25 | NULL     |    1609 |      0 |                 0 |
+----+------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go doesn't recognize NULL in particular. 
I think you can achieve it using a raw query in GORM. 
like this.

```
db.Raw("SELECT * FROM visit_details WHERE out_time is NULL order by id desc limit 1").Scan(&visitDetail)
```

This is one one to fetch the column. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You can set OutTime as a pointer so that it could be null. As seen in the [doc](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#gorm-Model):

```
type YourStruct struct {
     OutTime *time.Time
}
```

Then run your query

```
db.Where("out_time = ?", nil).Last(&visitDetail)
```

Comment: This answer should have been accepted! (not all people are using gorm)

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

Just specify `IS NULL` in the query without the wildcard.

```golang
db.Where("out_time IS NULL").Last(&visitDetail)
```

Answer (score -2):

The correct code is :

```
db.Where("out_time is ?", nil).Last(&visitDetail)
```

Comment: Hey Artem. This answer repeats @Emmanuel answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)