# Insert NULL for time.Time decoded from JSON

Tags: json, go, mariadb, go-gorm

I am prototyping a REST endpoints over an existing production DB and got stuck with nullable datetime column. I have already read threads like [Nullable time.Time in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564619/nullable-time-time-in-golang) or [Fetching NULL datetime value in MySQL using GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899014/fetching-null-datetime-value-in-mysql-using-gorm) but can't POST a new object to REST endpoint and store unlisted datetime-typed attribute from JSON as NULL into MariaDB.

I am submitting a HTTP request like

```
POST /countries
{ "iso_code" : "CZ", "title" : "Czechia" }
```

The table has following schema

```sql
create table country
(
    iso_code   char(2)                              not null comment 'Country alpha-2 ISO code'
        primary key,
    title      varchar(255)                         null comment 'Country name',
    created_on datetime default current_timestamp() not null,
    updated_on datetime                             null on update current_timestamp()
)
```

I have already tried mysql.NullTime type, time.Time type as pointer, specifying sql:DEFAULT:NULL in mapping, gorm:"null" mapping, I have also directly assigned nil into newCountry.UpdatedAt right before saving it. BeforeSave gorm hook also did not make difference.

The mode is quite explicite

```golang
    type Country struct {
        IsoCode string `json:"iso_code" gorm:"primary_key" sql:"size:2"`
        Title *string `json:"title,omitempty" gorm:"null" sql:"size:255"`
        CreatedAt *time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty" gorm:"column:created_on"`
       UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty" gorm:"column:updated_on;null" sql:"DEFAULT:NULL"`
    }
```

I am using GORM to store the object

```
func CreateCountry(country *m.Country) *m.Country {
    fmt.Println(country)

    existingCountry := GetCountry(country.IsoCode)
    if existingCountry == nil {
        err := GetDB().Create(country).Error
        // ...
    } 
    // ...
}
```

Here in method the country does not have value for `UpdatedAt` but `Create(country)` is called, it stores exact value to both datetime columns.

I am reading that from HTTP request body like this

```
var CreateCountry = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Body)

    newCountry := &m.Country{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(newCountry)
    // ...
}
```

Also here the body have nil in datetime attributes.

Not sure what else can be done to produce insert statement like

```sql
INSERT  INTO `country` (`iso_code`,
`title`,`created_on`,`updated_on`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)[KR 0xc0001f6130 null null]
```

and not

```sql
INSERT  INTO `country` (`iso_code`,
`title`,`created_on`,`updated_on`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)[KR 0xc0001f6130 2019-03-31 03:16:41.5158848 +0200 CEST m=+16.4487208
01 2019-03-31 03:16:41.5158848 +0200 CEST m=+16.448720801]
```

Comment: What if you say `nil` instead of `null` in `[KR 0xc0001f6130 null null]`?