# how to handling DB logging in golang

Tags: mysql, go

```golang
var accessPoint string 
err = db.Raw('
    select s.domain
    from servers as s
    inner join organization o on s.org_seq = o.seq
    inner join sso_user u on u.organization = o.organization
    where s.role = ? and s.status = 1 and u.user_uuid = ?
    order by rand() limit 1;
', role, d.UserUuid).Scan(&accessPoint).Error
if err != nil {
    db.Rollback()
    return
}
db.Commit()
return
```

Query to get domain of the server using the variable `useruuid`, `role`.
When the result of this query is not found, I want to check which value, useruuid or role, triggered the "not found" condition.

**I'm curious if it's the right way to distinguish like this.**
**If there's no need to make such a distinction, please let me know.**

I modified it like the query below, and I wonder if this is the right way.

```golang
var accessPoint string
var res string 

result := db.Raw(`  
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM organization AS o
        INNER JOIN sso_user AS u ON o.organization = u.organization
        INNER JOIN servers AS s ON o.seq = s.org_seq
        WHERE u.user_uuid = ?
    ) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM servers AS s
                WHERE s.role = ?
            ) THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM servers AS s
                        WHERE s.role = ? AND s.status = 1
                    ) THEN
                        (SELECT s.domain
                        FROM servers AS s
                        WHERE s.role = ? AND s.status = 1
                        LIMIT 1)
                    ELSE "ALL_SERVER_DOWN"
                END
            ELSE "ROLE_NOT_FOUND"
        END
    ELSE "ORGANIZATION_NOTFOUND"
END AS res;
`, d.UserUuid, role, role, role).Scan(&accessPoint)
if result.Error != nil {
    db.Rollback()
    return "", fmt.Errorf("get access point: %w", result.Error)
}
switch res {
case "ORGANIZATION_NOTFOUND":
    db.Rollback()
    return "", configs.ErrNotFoundOrg
case "ROLE_NOT_FOUND":
    db.Rollback()
    return "", configs.ErrNotFoundRole
case "ALL_SERVER_DOWN":
    db.Rollback()
    return "", configs.ErrServerNotRunning
}
db.Commit()
return
```

Comment: Please show us the definitions for `m` and `res`. I suspect that just [using a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48907021/11810946) will be sufficient.

Comment: thank you for your comments, i just updated

Comment: you still did not show `res`. what type is it

Comment: oh.. i added res type sry